# JSON: reading data inside a category

Tags: javascript, json

this is the JSON document I'm trying to read data from:

```
{title": "some name here",
                "details": {
                  "color": "red",
                  "location": "at home",
                  "shape": "square"
                }}
```

I'm trying to read this data in my js file and then add this to html.
Here's my code:

```
$http.get('/api/dataIuse')
  .success(function(rdata) {
    $scope.title = rdata['title'];
    $scope.details = rdata['details'];
    $scope.fullData = rdata;
    console.log(rdata['title']);
  })
  .error(function(rdata) {
    console.log('Error: ' + rdata);
  });
```

How can I read inside of 'details' to get color, location and shape seperately??

This is my guess (it doesn't work):

```
$scope.details.color = rdata['details.color'];
$scope.details.location = rdata['details.location'];
$scope.details.shape = rdata['details.shape'];
```

What method of reading JSON should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: `rdata.details.color` doesn't work?

Comment: `$scope.details = rdata.details;`. This will copy entire `details` node. You can then use either  `rdata.details.color`, `rdata.details.location` and `rdata.details.shape` or directly, `$scope.details`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
var rdata = {"title": "some name here",
                "details": {
                  "color": "red",
                  "location": "at home",
                  "shape": "square"
                }}
                
var color = rdata.details.color;
var area = rdata.details.location;
var shape = rdata.details.shape;
console.log(color);
console.log(area);
console.log(shape);
//or if you want to iterate through the object
Object.keys(rdata.details).forEach(function(item){
  console.log(rdata.details[item]);
})
```